# Picture file without extension

Tags: pictures

I download with Firefox (in the section Information-->View Page Information-->Media) a picture without extension (I attach it). How can I open it? I tried with windows picture viewer and with Chrome. The last give a page which is full of codes.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00784306336257548622

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to right-click and select **Open with**: choose one of the graphics programs on your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the file in a hex editor, I see the file is in the SVG format.  Rename the file and add the extension `.SVG` (Scalable Vector Graphics) and you will be able to open it in Internet Explorer, Chrome, or Firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Try appending ".jpg" to the end of the file and see if that helps. If not, it may be that you in fact downloaded something else in the belief that it was an image.

Comment: It seems rather hasty to assume that just because something isn't a jpeg means it's probably not an image at all. There are many other image formats.

Comment: True, but it is a file format that would be assigned to open with the poster's image viewer, which would open it regardless of format unless it was very exotic.

Comment: Such as the not at all exotic [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format, which [Windows Picture Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Viewer) does not support?